# How to get properties injected into test class in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot

How can I load the properties from my application-test.properties into my test class in Spring Boot ? I am doing something wrong but not able to figure it out ?

I am able to fetch the properties from application.properties for my Configuration class given below

```
package org.vinodh.testing;

import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import lombok.Data;

@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "caching")
@Data
public class CachingConfig {

    @Value("${caching.name}")
    private String name;

    @Data
    public static class CacheSpec {
        private int minutesToExpire;
        private int maximumSize;

    }

    private Map<String, CacheSpec> specs;

    @Bean
    public void test() {
        System.out.println(name);
        System.out.println(specs);
    }

}
```

but when I try to do the same in the test class am getting null see below code. How can I get my test class to print the values from properties file ?

```
package org.vinodh.testing;

import java.util.Map;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.TestPropertySource;

import lombok.Data;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "caching")
@TestPropertySource("/application-test.properties")
@Data
public class CachingConfigTest {

    @Value("${caching.name}")
    private String name;

    @Data
    public static class CacheSpec {
        private int minutesToExpire;
        private int maximumSize;
    }

    private Map<String, CacheSpec> specs;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        System.out.println(name);
        System.out.println(specs);
    }

}
```

application.properties

```
caching.specs.test.minutesToExpire=10
caching.specs.test.maximumSize=10
caching.name=Vinodh
```

application-test.properties

```
caching.specs.test.minutesToExpire=10
caching.specs.test.maximumSize=10
caching.name=Vinodh
```

Comment: Add `@ActiveProfile("test")`.

Comment: properties should be spelled like ```caching.specs.test.minutes-to-expire=10``` and ```caching.specs.test.maximum-size=5```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you don't need to create `CacheSpec` in test class which is also not recommended, you can use the original one from source package. But just add `getter` to private map `specs` in `CachingConfig`

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@Profile("test")
public class CachingConfigTest {

    @Autowired
    private CachingConfig cachingConfig;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        System.out.println(cachingConfig.getSpecs());
     }

 }
```

And also you don't need `@TestPropertySource`, you can just use `@Profile` to load test profile and `@ActiveProfile` to make `test` as active profile for that test class

Answer (score 0):

Try this
    spring.config.additional-location=classpath:/application-test.properties